# SwiftUI onDisappear not being called

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using a `ScrollView` and `VStack` to present bunch of views in a list. But for some reason the `onDisappear` is not being called, the `onAppear` was though.

Does `onDisappear` only call when that view has disappeared off the screen? Or when it's deinitialized

```
struct AView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0...99, id: \.self) { _ in
                    SomeView()
                        .onDisappear {
                            print("Disappeared")
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all view inside the ForEach is part of AView so when the screen change then onDisappear method will call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're using `VStack`, it's gonna draw all the views inside - all of them are added to the view tree, it doesn't matter wether it's visible on the screen.

If you replace it with `LazyVStack` it'll make content lazy - only visible views will be added to the view tree and `onDisappear` will be called as you expect it.